# NSFetchedResultsController per cell in a collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a collectionView with `NSFetchedResultsController`. Some cells in the `collectionView` will have extra embedded UI elements queried from core data, and those extra embedded UI elements also need the update functionality of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

So my question is, what is the recommended way of approaching this?

Since the number of cells, and whether or not each of them has embedded UI elements depends on the data actually fetched from server, we cannot use `sectionKeyPath` of NSFRC right?

EDIT: the extra UI elements are not the same model as the embedding cells and thus require separate queries (`NSPredicate`).

EDIT: Our core data model:

```
RelationModel
   type
   status
   Relationships(fromProfile, toProfile)

ProfileModel
   ..many fields
   Relationships(photos)
```

Basically, the extra UI elements will be toProfiles with the embedding cell being the fromProfile. But because there are more than one kind of relations in the app, we decided to have a separate model for relations. And I found it hard to set a relationship from ProfileModel to the RelationModel

Comment: Are there core-data relationships between all the entities that are effecting the UI?

Comment: If you are creating a separate fetchedResultsContoller for every cell then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: It's wrong because it's not doable or because of performance issues? 
Would you mind referencing documentation for this?

Comment: It is a big red flag that you are doing something wrong.  Either your data is not structured correctly, or you are not understanding how fetchedResultsControlles are supposed to work.

Comment: Or our app logics happen to be difficult and need some workaround. Still, please tell me exactly why you are restricting one object query one view. Can’t there be a complex screen that tries to show many things?

Comment: If  extra UI elements are based on data that is accessible from the main (ie monitored) object then you should be able to display via the relationship it has.  If there is relationship then I would strongly suspect that is a mistake.

Comment: @JonRose solid point. But can you compare the cost of having separate FRC with possible optimization using cache vs. having to do query every time? Also, remember that I need the ability to monitor the extra elements too. Can anything other than frc monitor queries?

Comment: don't do a query every time.  Use the relationship.  Relationship are super fast.  Monitoring is a challenge, and there are many solutions.  Using multiple FRC is the worst solution.  If you edit you question to explain what you setup is I can advise on a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we require separate queries in each cell, we ended up setting separate `NSFetchedResultsController` in each cell when it's dequeued. And then have the `NSFetchedResultsController` set as nil when `prepareForReuse`.

Answer (score 1):

A `NSFetchedResultsController` is a really cool object.  It does a fetch and then monitors core-data for changes. While it has an interface that relies on indexPaths so it is natural to think of these indexPath's as the same indexPaths as your collectionView there is no requirement that you do that.  The indexPaths of the fetchedResultsController can be different than the indexPaths of the collectionView - you just need to careful about keeping track which indexPaths you are dealing with and translating from one to the other.

For example: You have a set of widgets that you fetching from core data.  Some of the widgets have a property of extraWidgetInfo which you want to display in you UI as an extra cell.  The fetchedResultsController says that there are 4 element (all in section 0).  But the collectionView can display that as

[section1] widget1,

[section2] widget2, widget 2 extra info,

[section3] widget3,

[section4] widget4, widget 4 extra info.

While the fetchedResultsController only says that there are 4 elements, there are 6 cells in the collectionView.  You would also have to translate the fetchedResultsController indexPath when dealing with updates.  An update would translate to a reload section, and an add would translate to an insertSection and insert of some amount of rows in that section.  You could also just call reloadData when core data updates (If you data is updating rarely this may not be a bad option).

Comment: Thanks for those detailed insights! I added an EDIT in my original question. So basically I cannot do this with one NSFetchedResultsController. And the data models are pretty settled down now. 
I ended up with a solution that I am posting as the answer for this question to share.

Comment: Can you give me some other suggestion for monitoring changes? I have edited my question.